# Php drop down to post choice to another table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a script in php that pulls information for a dropdown list.  When I hit post, I want what ever my selection is from the drop down list to post in another Table called `techissuses`.

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
<?php mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Connection Failed");
mysql_select_db("mysqli")or die("Connection Failed"); 
$query = "SELECT * FROM manufactures"; $result = MySQL_query($query); ?> <select name="select1"> 
<?php while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { ?>
< <option value="<?php echo $line['name'];?>"> 
 <?php echo $line['name'];?>
  </option>   <?php } ?>  </select>

First name: <input type="text" name="firstname"> 

Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname">

Age: <input type="text" name="age">

 <input type="submit">
 </form>
```

This is the `insert.php` that will write to `Techissues` enter code here:

```
 // escape variables for security
$firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['firstname']);
 $lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['lastname']);
$age = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['age']);
$Techissues = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['techissues']);
$sql="INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age, Techissues)
VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$age', '$techissues')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
 ?>
```

Comment: Would you please talk more about what you would like to achieve and format your code better?

Comment: I wish I could format better im learning this setup its the reason I don't really ask questions. I want the fourth line down select from manufactures drop down box to post the choice some one chooses back to a table called Techissues

Comment: I don't see the problem here... If you're asking what I think you are, why not just change the name of the `<select>` to `"techissues"`? That way, it will get put into `$_POST["techissues"]` , which seems to be what you want. Or are there any other problems with the code?

Comment: the select name is there the roplem is when I post it takes all the required information and inserts it into the database except techissues it sows a line has been added but its blank

Comment: i have my data bases column techissues set to be text what should i set it to be if not text?

Comment: ok it reports to my database now but it only reports the first letter from manufactures instead of the whole name.

Comment: Instead of trying to work around the flaws in the deprecated mysql_ functions, you should use a new database method that doesn't depend on your never making a mistake to avoid injection.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).